# What do the day/night panels do in Kirby’s Dream Course?

Tags: kirbys-dream-course

Some of the 2-player stages in Kirby’s Dream Course have a sun/moon panel. Hitting it switched the stage from day to night, but didn’t seem to have any effect on gameplay.

What does hitting the day/night panel do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [this guide](https://gamefaqs.gamespot.com/snes/588427-kirbys-dream-course/faqs/34683), hitting the panel will swap your and your opponent's star points for that level.

Comment: It looks like you can hit the panel 3 times per level before it becomes unusable